# Replace contents of a file and save file in directory - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to change contents of a file based on a pattern and save the file in the same directory. Below is my code,

```
designFile <- "/proj/desk/design.scs"
designFile <- readLines(designFile)
pattern <- "esd_event"     
rownos <- grep(pattern, designfile)
rownotoreplace <- rownos[length(rownos)]
print(designfile[rownotoreplace])
designFile[rownotoreplace] <- paste("+ esd_event=", input$esd_event, sep="")
filename = designfile         
fConn <- file(filename,open="w")
for(i in 1:length(designFile)){
  writeLines(designFile[i], con = fConn, sep = "") 
}
close(fConn)
```

The file in which the string change looks like,

```
+ cor_zgdiode   = sigma
+ corner_sigma  = 3
+ corner_sigma_sg = corner_sigma
+ corner_sigma_eg = corner_sigma
+ corner_sigma_sram = corner_sigma
+ corner_sigma_ldmos = corner_sigma
+ corner_sigma_wire = corner_sigma
+ cor_noin      = 0
+ cor_noip      = 0
+ cor_tnoin     = 0
+ cor_tnoip     = 0
+ fnoi_cor_sgn_sw    = cor_noin
+ fnoi_cor_egn_sw    = cor_noin
+ fnoi_mc_sgn_sw    = 1
+ fnoi_mc_egn_sw    = 1
+ fnoi_cor_sgp_sw    = cor_noip
+ fnoi_cor_egp_sw    = cor_noip
+ fnoi_mc_sgp_sw    = 1
+ fnoi_mc_egp_sw    = 1
* ESD Global switches ********
+ esd_event=0
+ esd_exit=1
+ esd_extr=0
```

The contents of the file is dynamic and the number of lines might vary based on user input. I'm able to replace the string, "esd_event" with my code that I attached, but I'm not able to save the file in the same directory after replacing the string.

I would like to know how to save.

Comment: It's writeLines not writeLine ;). Just try `writeLines(designFile,filename)`

Comment: Also, you are switching between `designfile` and `designFile` and using both for the filename and for the data, which could explain all sorts of weird behaviour you might be seeing.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I'm unable to save the file. When I writeLines I'm able to replace. But I would like to save the entire after replacing the string.

Comment: See my second comment and have a closer look at your code.